# Reviewing Flagged Posts?

Tags: support

I have not seen this functionality before, but there is a new flag count in the header that shows up when a post is flagged (the 1 in the yellow square):

[image]

The odd thing is that once I action on the flagged item, the count doesn't get updated. I just get an empty list when I click the 1.

[image]

What is going on here? Shouldn't the count be reduced to zero once I have actioned it? I'm just trying to figure this functionality out.

Comment: I think it's a bug which will get fixed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212285/flagged-question-count-is-wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think that there might be some lag time or it is a bug.

I have also observed that if I review something the box doesn't always go away; however, I have seen that the items that I reviewed were still there.  Specifically I marked something to be Deleted and it didn't go away.  When I clicked to Delete it again, I got an error message that I already Deleted it, or something to that effect.

I don't see the items that I reviewed anymore, but it's been a few hours since I looked.

I just noticed today that it keeps the number in the bar, but the page then shows me that I've already reviewed some of them.  In the case where I hadn't reviewed all of them it showed the ones that I reviewed as faded.  In the case where I already reviewed all of them I got a message with a link to show posts I've already flagged.  Note how it still has the 4 in the nav bar.

[image: showPosts]

Comment: There's a lot of Ajax on the site. I find that nav bar counters are sometimes out of date. A page refresh usually brings things up to date.

Comment: @metadaddy I thought the same thing so I shift+refreshed to clear the cache and get it to reload but it still didn't work. It is a bit odd. I'll have to keep an eye on it. Maybe it is just my browser, Chrome on Mac. Not a big deal, was just curious if anyone had experienced this as well.

Comment: @JesseAltman - I thought that as well and did the same and had the same results.

Comment: Weird - maybe an artifact of the new nav bar